# jQuery and doing event always once

Tags: jquery

There are a couple buttons:

```
<button id="bid1">button 1</button>
<button id="bid2">button 2</button>
```

and I'am trying to put some event to the second button

```
$("#bid1").click(function() {
    $("#bid2").click(function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

If I press the first button several times and press the second button. How to put the second button click-event that it alerts always once (not the number of times pressed the first button)? Thank you!

Comment: you want to bind the click event for second button only ater first button click?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi that's what it sounds like to me, but the question isn't clear, and the comments below would suggest otherwise :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The way you are writing click event handlers is wrong. Binding a click handler inside other is not right, though it works for you.
2. Use **[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** for second button.

---

```
$("#bid1").click(function() {

});

$("#bid2").one('click',function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: @user2301515 , you accepted the wrong answer I guess. Your requirement was already satisfied by Rajaprabhu's answer

Comment: :) Man..  This actually let the OP to know about a new function `.one()`.. So this should be the accepted one.. :):)

Answer (score 2):

Then bind those events individually,

```
$("#bid1").click(function() {

});

$("#bid2").click(function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

What is the thing going behind the screen is, whenever you making a click in the first button a click event for second button is getting bound.. So the alert which is inside the second button's click event will displays as many times you clicked the first button.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt4LU/)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/one/ will help you

```
$("#bid1").one()
```

Comment: OP meant that the click event fires multiple times for the second button, not once.. He is not asking for `.one()` function..

Comment: second buttons is not affected with this code, it still has the standard click event

Answer (score 0):

I solved

```
$("#bid1").unbind('click').click(function() {
    $("#bid2").click(function() {
        alert(2);
    });
});
```

hopefully it works